# C# Extending Classes from DLL

Tags: c#, dll, game-engine

Okay, this should be a pretty simple question

I'm working on a game engine type thing that needs to dynamically load external DLLs that contain mod content.  The question is basically thus:

I have, within my engine, the following:

```
public class Mod
{
    public abstract void OnLoad(ModLoadedArgs args);
}
```

If I were to put, in the DLL, the following:

```
public class ContentMod : Mod
{
    public void OnLoad(ModLoadedArgs args)
    {
        BaseEngine.Dictionary.Register(new Thing()); // BaseEngine.Dictionary is
                                                     // a static object
    }
}
```

Would this work properly?

Sorry for the basic question, I'm new to working with DLLs and don't have access to an IDE on my laptop or I would try myself.

EDIT 1:

So... So far so good, except .Load doesn't seem to change the oreDict object I have in Program.cs
I feel like this is a stupid problem, but hurts my head nonetheless.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(files[i]);
foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
{
    if (t is Mod)
    {
        ((Mod)t).Load(new ModOnLoadArgs(oreDict));
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

So I added a 'Console.WriteLine' call in the Load function of my Mod, and nothing comes up. It should say something, right? I'm not going crazy? Could I test this better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DLL would need a reference to your engine, which is a bit inconvenient, since this will make it more difficult to change stuff in your engine -- you have to be careful not to break backwards compatibility to your DLL developers.

Another solution would be to create a **library** that only contains the interfaces required by the mod designers:

```
public interface IMod
{
    void OnLoad(ModLoadedArgs args);
}
```

This interface library would be referenced both by your engine and by the mod developers -- it's the *contract* between the two systems. This interface would change rarely, and you are free to develop and modify your engine as you wish.

Comment: Okay, so here's the question. How would I implement my Dictionary within the Engine? Is the dictionary a class within the library that is, in turn, referenced by the engine?

Comment: @UnrealSpartan: You could include a reference to the dictionary in `ModLoadedArgs`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Time to start testing things to figure out how they work

Comment: Okay, another question really quickly. I have a reference to my 'Dictionary' within the 'ModLoadedArgs' and load the assembly as edited in the question above:
The Load function of the assembly (that is being loaded, I test that elsewhere) uses the Args class and registers the things in the 'Dictionary' (just a 'List' for now), but the 'Dictionary' in 'Program.cs' doesn't reflect that change. Any ideas?

Comment: @UnrealSpartan: Hmm... good question, your code (I saw the proposed edit) looks fine. There must be some other bug somewhere. Maybe create a minimal, self-contained example and post it in a new question?